# How to test image upload with nested json data in mocha

Tags: node.js, json, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

This is my test snippet. I need to pass additional data with nested json along with image.

`

```
const email = 'test.email@gmail.com';
const contact = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    phone: '9876543212'
  };

const response = await chai
    .request(server)
    .post('/profile')
    .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
    .attach('logo', 'test/test-images/logo.png')
    .field({
      email,
      name: 'All Tech Solutions',
      phone: '9812345678',
      contact: contact
    });

  expect(response.body.status).to.equal('created');
  expect(response.body.profile.email).to.equal(email);
  expect(response.body.profile.logo).to.exist;
});
```

`

It works with parameters without nested json but doesnot work with nested json. How can I pass nested json with logo?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @slideshowp2 it says contact is not multipart value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `.field()` method signature:

```
field(name: string, val: MultipartValue): this;
field(fields: { [fieldName: string]: MultipartValue }): this;
```

And `MultipartValue` type:

```
type MultipartValueSingle = Blob | Buffer | fs.ReadStream | string | boolean | number;

type MultipartValue = MultipartValueSingle | MultipartValueSingle[];
```

The value of the field should be `Blob | Buffer | fs.ReadStream | string | boolean | number;`. It doesn't accept objects.

So you need to use `JSON.stringify(contact)`.

E.g.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const upload = multer({ dest: path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads/') });

const app = express();

app.post('/profile', upload.single('logo'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
  const profile = { email: req.body.email, logo: true };
  res.json({ status: 'created', profile });
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const server = require('./app');
const chai = require('chai');
const path = require('path');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('66273169', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const email = 'test.email@gmail.com';
    const contact = {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      phone: '9876543212',
    };

    const response = await chai
      .request(server)
      .post('/profile')
      .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
      .attach('logo', path.resolve(__dirname, 'logo.png'))
      .field({
        email,
        name: 'All Tech Solutions',
        phone: '9812345678',
        contact: JSON.stringify(contact),
      });

    expect(response.body.status).to.equal('created');
    expect(response.body.profile.email).to.equal(email);
    expect(response.body.profile.logo).to.exist;
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  66273169
[Object: null prototype] {
  email: 'test.email@gmail.com',
  name: 'All Tech Solutions',
  phone: '9812345678',
  contact: '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","phone":"9876543212"}'
}
{
  fieldname: 'logo',
  originalname: 'logo.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: '/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66273169/uploads',
  filename: '7b82676df1678c79da43abcfbd9d411f',
  path: '/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66273169/uploads/7b82676df1678c79da43abcfbd9d411f',
  size: 0
}
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (31ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```